# Bad CTE performance since Postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have the following query which uses a common table expression :

```
with cte (
    select gateway_id,
    parameters.id as parameter_id
from
    gateways
inner join capturing_devices on
    gateway_id = gateways.id
inner join capturing_device_types on
    capturing_device_type_id = capturing_device_types.id
inner join parameters on
    capturing_device_id = capturing_devices.id
where
    capturing_device_types.name = 'ENERGY_COMFOAIR'
    and inactive = false) select
    distinct gateway_id,
    null as capturing_device_id
from
    cte master
where
    not exists (
        select *
    from
        parameter_values
    inner join cte on
        parameter_values.parameter_id = cte.parameter_id
    where
        gateway_id = master.gateway_id
        and datetime >= now() - interval '120 minutes')
    and not exists (
        select *
    from
        alerts
    inner join alert_types on
        alert_type_id = alert_types.id
    where
        alert_types.name = 'gateway_offline'
        and alerts.gateway_id = master.gateway_id
        and actual_status = 0)
    and not exists (
        select *
    from
        alerts
    inner join alert_types on
        alert_type_id = alert_types.id
    where
        alert_types.name = 'one_energy_offline'
        and alerts.gateway_id = master.gateway_id
        and actual_status = 0);
```

This is the EXPLAIN: (I tried with ANALYSE but aborted after >1 hour running without any result).

```
Unique  (cost=7920.48..51410365.98 rows=1 width=36)
  CTE cte
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.88..7653.69 rows=121 width=12)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.46..7633.26 rows=22 width=12)
                ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.18..7622.70 rows=23 width=12)
                      Hash Cond: (capturing_devices.capturing_device_type_id = capturing_device_types.id)
                      ->  Seq Scan on capturing_devices  (cost=0.00..7539.77 rows=28377 width=16)
                      ->  Hash  (cost=8.17..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
                            ->  Index Scan using index_capturing_device_types_on_name on capturing_device_types  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
                                  Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'ENERGY_COMFOAIR'::text)
                ->  Index Scan using gateways_pkey on gateways  (cost=0.28..0.46 rows=1 width=8)
                      Index Cond: (id = capturing_devices.gateway_id)
                      Filter: (NOT inactive)
          ->  Index Scan using parameters_type_device_unique on parameters  (cost=0.42..0.82 rows=11 width=12)
                Index Cond: (capturing_device_id = capturing_devices.id)
  ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=266.79..51402712.28 rows=1 width=36)
        Merge Cond: (master.gateway_id = alerts.gateway_id)
        ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=266.35..51263410.78 rows=1 width=4)
              Join Filter: (cte.gateway_id = master.gateway_id)
              ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=262.42..263.04 rows=121 width=4)
                    Merge Cond: (master.gateway_id = alerts_1.gateway_id)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=6.61..6.91 rows=121 width=4)
                          Sort Key: master.gateway_id
                          ->  CTE Scan on cte master  (cost=0.00..2.42 rows=121 width=4)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=255.81..255.81 rows=2 width=4)
                          Sort Key: alerts_1.gateway_id
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.47..255.80 rows=2 width=4)
                                Hash Cond: (alerts_1.alert_type_id = alert_types_1.id)
                                ->  Index Scan using index_alerts_on_actual_status on alerts alerts_1  (cost=0.29..245.86 rows=663 width=8)
                                      Index Cond: (actual_status = 0)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=8.17..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
                                      ->  Index Scan using index_alert_types_on_name on alert_types alert_types_1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
                                            Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'one_energy_offline'::text)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.93..51257927.36 rows=306637950 width=4)
                    Hash Cond: (parameter_values_202006.parameter_id = cte.parameter_id)
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..46290895.48 rows=506839587 width=4)
                          Subplans Removed: 30
                          ->  Seq Scan on parameter_values_202006  (cost=0.00..452878.48 rows=446392 width=4)
                                Filter: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on parameter_values_202007  (cost=18.19..38.98 rows=617 width=4)
                                Recheck Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on parameter_values_202007_pkey  (cost=0.00..18.03 rows=617 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on parameter_values_202008  (cost=18.19..38.98 rows=617 width=4)
                                Recheck Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on parameter_values_202008_pkey  (cost=0.00..18.03 rows=617 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on parameter_values_202009  (cost=18.19..38.98 rows=617 width=4)
                                Recheck Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on parameter_values_202009_pkey  (cost=0.00..18.03 rows=617 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on parameter_values_202010  (cost=18.19..38.98 rows=617 width=4)
                                Recheck Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on parameter_values_202010_pkey  (cost=0.00..18.03 rows=617 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on parameter_values_202011  (cost=18.19..38.98 rows=617 width=4)
                                Recheck Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on parameter_values_202011_pkey  (cost=0.00..18.03 rows=617 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on parameter_values_202012  (cost=18.19..38.98 rows=617 width=4)
                                Recheck Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on parameter_values_202012_pkey  (cost=0.00..18.03 rows=617 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=2.42..2.42 rows=121 width=12)
                          ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..2.42 rows=121 width=12)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.44..139301.48 rows=2 width=4)
              Join Filter: (alerts.alert_type_id = alert_types.id)
              ->  Index Scan using index_alerts_on_gateway_id on alerts  (cost=0.29..139283.37 rows=663 width=8)
                    Filter: (actual_status = 0)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
                    ->  Index Scan using index_alert_types_on_name on alert_types  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
                          Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'gateway_offline'::text)
```

This query takes > 10 minutes to run since Postgres 12 (in Postgres 11 this was well under 30 seconds).

I have tried rewriting it like:

```
with cte AS MATERIALIZED
```

which doesn't make any difference (and which is logical since that would be the default since the CTE is used more than once).

I've also rewritten as:

```
with cte AS NOT MATERIALIZED
```

which causes the query to run in 11 seconds.  This is the EXPLAIN of that:

```
Unique  (cost=17785.43..20839996.12 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=5924.141..23039.116 rows=23 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=295370
  ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=17785.43..20839996.12 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=5924.139..23039.001 rows=149 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=295370
        ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=17760.41..20839959.05 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1294.347..22785.000 rows=2713 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (capturing_devices_1.gateway_id = capturing_devices.gateway_id)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 145357066
              Buffers: shared hit=210823
              ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=8088.45..8089.07 rows=121 width=4) (actual time=42.344..55.647 rows=19951 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (capturing_devices.gateway_id = alerts_1.gateway_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=14452
                    ->  Sort  (cost=7832.64..7832.94 rows=121 width=4) (actual time=41.576..46.396 rows=28669 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: capturing_devices.gateway_id
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2112kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=14095
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.88..7828.45 rows=121 width=4) (actual time=0.172..34.577 rows=28669 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=14095
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.46..7750.49 rows=22 width=12) (actual time=0.156..20.694 rows=1064 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=10590
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.18..7622.70 rows=23 width=12) (actual time=0.111..16.987 rows=1109 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (capturing_devices.capturing_device_type_id = capturing_device_types.id)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=7261
                                            ->  Seq Scan on capturing_devices  (cost=0.00..7539.77 rows=28377 width=16) (actual time=0.008..9.623 rows=28377 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=7256
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=8.17..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                  ->  Index Scan using index_capturing_device_types_on_name on capturing_device_types  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'ENERGY_COMFOAIR'::text)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=2
                                      ->  Index Scan using gateways_pkey on gateways  (cost=0.28..5.56 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1109)
                                            Index Cond: (id = capturing_devices.gateway_id)
                                            Filter: (NOT inactive)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                            Buffers: shared hit=3329
                                ->  Index Only Scan using index_parameters_on_capturing_device_id on parameters  (cost=0.42..3.43 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.008 rows=27 loops=1064)
                                      Index Cond: (capturing_device_id = capturing_devices.id)
                                      Heap Fetches: 253
                                      Buffers: shared hit=3505
                    ->  Sort  (cost=255.81..255.81 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.762..0.869 rows=320 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: alerts_1.gateway_id
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 40kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=357
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.47..255.80 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.055..0.665 rows=321 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (alerts_1.alert_type_id = alert_types_1.id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=357
                                ->  Index Scan using index_alerts_on_actual_status on alerts alerts_1  (cost=0.29..245.86 rows=663 width=8) (actual time=0.021..0.448 rows=689 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (actual_status = 0)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=355
                                ->  Hash  (cost=8.17..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=2
                                      ->  Index Scan using index_alert_types_on_name on alert_types alert_types_1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'one_energy_offline'::text)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=2
              ->  Materialize  (cost=9671.97..20822017.28 rows=386130 width=4) (actual time=0.039..0.508 rows=7287 loops=19951)
                    Buffers: shared hit=196371
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=9671.97..20818577.63 rows=386130 width=4) (actual time=766.869..1211.087 rows=42765 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (capturing_devices_1.gateway_id = gateways_1.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=196371
                          ->  Gather  (cost=8504.71..20816314.46 rows=417152 width=4) (actual time=764.591..1195.184 rows=42765 loops=1)
                                Workers Planned: 4
                                Workers Launched: 4
                                Buffers: shared hit=195316
                                ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=7504.71..20773599.26 rows=104288 width=4) (actual time=725.830..1219.735 rows=8553 loops=5)
                                      Hash Cond: (parameter_values_202006.parameter_id = parameters_1.id)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=195316
                                      ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..20290503.38 rows=126709895 width=4) (actual time=552.325..1178.649 rows=76567 loops=5)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=160027
                                            Subplans Removed: 30
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parameter_values_202006  (cost=0.00..233239.87 rows=111598 width=4) (actual time=552.319..1166.660 rows=76567 loops=5)
                                                  Filter: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 3278945
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=160027
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parameter_values_202007  (cost=0.00..29.04 rows=363 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parameter_values_202008  (cost=0.00..29.04 rows=363 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=2)
                                                  Filter: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parameter_values_202009  (cost=0.00..29.04 rows=363 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parameter_values_202010  (cost=0.00..29.04 rows=363 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=0 loops=2)
                                                  Filter: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parameter_values_202011  (cost=0.00..29.04 rows=363 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parameter_values_202012  (cost=0.00..29.04 rows=363 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: (datetime >= (now() - '02:00:00'::interval))
                                      ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=7504.05..7504.05 rows=53 width=12) (actual time=16.491..16.491 rows=5876 loops=5)
                                            Buckets: 32768 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1976kB
                                            Buffers: shared hit=35169
                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.60..7504.05 rows=53 width=12) (actual time=0.091..10.976 rows=5876 loops=5)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=35169
                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.18..7413.57 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.062..3.879 rows=222 loops=5)
                                                        Hash Cond: (capturing_devices_1.capturing_device_type_id = capturing_device_types_1.id)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=7270
                                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on capturing_devices capturing_devices_1  (cost=0.00..7374.24 rows=11824 width=16) (actual time=0.003..2.111 rows=5675 loops=5)
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=7256
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=8.17..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=5)
                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=14
                                                              ->  Index Scan using index_capturing_device_types_on_name on capturing_device_types capturing_device_types_1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=5)
                                                                    Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'ENERGY_COMFOAIR'::text)
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=14
                                                  ->  Index Scan using index_parameters_on_capturing_device_id on parameters parameters_1  (cost=0.42..8.94 rows=11 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.027 rows=26 loops=1109)
                                                        Index Cond: (capturing_device_id = capturing_devices_1.id)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=27899
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1107.04..1107.04 rows=4817 width=8) (actual time=2.262..2.262 rows=2201 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 150kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=1055
                                ->  Seq Scan on gateways gateways_1  (cost=0.00..1107.04 rows=4817 width=8) (actual time=0.014..1.743 rows=2201 loops=1)
                                      Filter: (NOT inactive)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 177
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1055
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=25.02..37.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.091..0.091 rows=1 loops=2713)
              Join Filter: (alerts.alert_type_id = alert_types.id)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 0
              Buffers: shared hit=84547
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on alerts  (cost=24.87..28.88 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.079..0.079 rows=1 loops=2713)
                    Recheck Cond: ((gateway_id = capturing_devices.gateway_id) AND (actual_status = 0))
                    Heap Blocks: exact=2598
                    Buffers: shared hit=79349
                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=24.87..24.87 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.074..0.074 rows=0 loops=2713)
                          Buffers: shared hit=76652
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_alerts_on_gateway_id  (cost=0.00..3.19 rows=37 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=57 loops=2713)
                                Index Cond: (gateway_id = capturing_devices.gateway_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=6114
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_alerts_on_actual_status  (cost=0.00..21.26 rows=663 width=0) (actual time=0.056..0.056 rows=730 loops=2713)
                                Index Cond: (actual_status = 0)
                                Buffers: shared hit=70538
              ->  Index Scan using index_alert_types_on_name on alert_types  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=2599)
                    Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'gateway_offline'::text)
                    Buffers: shared hit=5198
Planning Time: 6.546 ms
Execution Time: 23040.043 ms
```

If I run the CTE part alone it executes in 63ms and returns 200 rows.

When I rewrite the complete query with a temporary table like below it executes in 4 seconds.

```
select gateway_id, parameters.id as parameter_id 
into temporary tmp_gateway_params
from
    gateways
inner join capturing_devices on
    gateway_id = gateways.id
inner join capturing_device_types on
    capturing_device_type_id = capturing_device_types.id
inner join parameters on
    capturing_device_id = capturing_devices.id
where
    capturing_device_types.name = 'ENERGY_COMFOAIR'
    and inactive = false;

select
    distinct gateway_id,
    null as capturing_device_id
from
    tmp_gateway_params master
where
    not exists (
        select *
    from
        parameter_values
    inner join tmp_gateway_params on
        parameter_values.parameter_id = tmp_gateway_params.parameter_id
    where
        gateway_id = master.gateway_id
        and datetime >= now() - interval '120 minutes')
    and not exists (
        select *
    from
        alerts
    inner join alert_types on
        alert_type_id = alert_types.id
    where
        alert_types.name = 'gateway_offline'
        and alerts.gateway_id = master.gateway_id
        and actual_status = 0)
    and not exists (
        select *
    from
        alerts
    inner join alert_types on
        alert_type_id = alert_types.id
    where
        alert_types.name = 'one_energy_offline'
        and alerts.gateway_id = master.gateway_id
        and actual_status = 0);
```

This is the execution plan:

**First part:**

https://pastebin.com/WN0e9NnU

**Second part**

https://pastebin.com/jYeCyi9v

I already found some other person having performance issues with CTE's after the upgrade and he was able to solve it with:

```
set jit = off;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't make any difference.

EDIT:

After the weekend running the exact same query again returns results after less than 5 seconds.

This is the EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, BUFFERS):

https://pastebin.com/f74X1FfW

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow and the fast query, as well as for the queries with the temp table. Why not use the temp table if it is fast?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've added the EXPLAIN, however for the slow query I had to abort after one hour without any results.  I'm using a temp table for now as a workaround, it just doesn't feel right. Especially the fact that the query now takes over an hour, while in previous Postgres it was less than 10 seconds...

Comment: What is your goal?  It looks like you already know how to fix the problem with two different work-arounds.  Do you want to get the planner improved for some distant future version (probably 14 at least, as 13 is already in feature freeze)?  Do you think this is a back-patchable (into v12) bug?  I really doubt that it is.

Comment: Could you also show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) you are finding when run under v11?  Is the partitioning set up the same between versions?

Comment: The estimates are bad. Does it get faster if you set `enable_nestloop = off` for the duration of the query?

Comment: @jjanes my goal is to indeed to get the planner improved for some distant future version.  Especially the fact that it worked fast in version PG11 causes me concern.  I don't have the PG11 version online (DB is >300 GB).  Partitioning set didn't change.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe YES it does get faster with enable_nestloop = off !!  4 seconds.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if I run it now without the enable_nestloop (in a new session) it's also 4 seconds?  How is this possible?

Comment: How shall I answer that?

Comment: My standard trick is to avoid the CTE (especially if you expect a large number of records in it) and rewrite it to a TEMP VIEW, which will be pulled into the main query plan.

Comment: BTW: the estimates are bad. Did you run ANALYZE after import? `WITH NOT MATERIALIZED ...` (available since PG12) could produce the same effect as `enable_nestloop=off;`